# Segmentation Fault in Linux C++ but code is working in windows

Tags: c++, linux

AoA,
 Here is the code of multiplication of two matrices, which runs fine under 3x3 matrices but gives error on exceding row or column of 3x3, like on 3x4 and 4x3 it gives the error "segmentation fault"

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct matrix
{
    int** mat;
    int row;
    int col;
    matrix(int m,int n)
    {
        row = m;
        col = n;
        mat = new int*[row];
        for( int i=0;i<row;i++ )
        {
            mat[i] = new int[col];
            for( int k=0;k<col;k++ )
            {
                mat[i][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};

matrix* MultiplyMat(matrix* matA,matrix* matB)
{
    matrix* tMat = new matrix(matA->row,matB->col);
    if(matA->row == matB->col)
    {
        for( int i=0; i<matA->row; i++ )
        {
            for( int j=0;j<matB->col;j++ )
            {   
                for( int m=0;m<matB->col;m++ )
                {
                    tMat->mat[j][i] += matA->mat[j][m] * matB->mat[m][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return tMat;
}

void PrintMatrix(matrix* tMat)
{
    cout<<"Print: Matrix\n\n";
    for( int i=0;tMat->row;i++ )
    {
        for( int j=0;j<tMat->col;j++ )
        {
            cout<<" "<<tMat->mat[i][j];

        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

}

int main()
{
    matrix matB(3,4);
    matrix matA(4,3);

    matA.mat[0][0] = 2;
    matA.mat[0][1] = 1;
    matA.mat[0][2] = 4;
    matA.mat[1][0] = 6;
    matA.mat[1][1] = 5;
    matA.mat[1][2] = 9;
    matA.mat[2][0] = 8;
    matA.mat[2][1] = 7;
    matA.mat[2][2] = 11;
    matA.mat[3][0] = 5;
    matA.mat[3][1] = 5;
    matA.mat[3][2] = 9;

    matB.mat[0][0] = 2;
    matB.mat[0][1] = 1;
    matB.mat[0][2] = 4;
    matB.mat[0][3] = 3;
    matB.mat[1][0] = 6;
    matB.mat[1][1] = 5;
    matB.mat[1][2] = 9;
    matB.mat[1][3] = 12;
    matB.mat[2][0] = 8;
    matB.mat[2][1] = 7;
    matB.mat[2][2] = 11;
    matB.mat[2][3] = 13;

    matrix* matC = MultiplyMat(&matA,&matB);
    PrintMatrix(matC);


    return 0;
}
```

I am just trying to multiplay two matrices, the g++ compiler gives error "segmentation fault" I have tried debuging method(found on this site) but failed to remove the error!

Any help?

Comment: You allocate space for `tMat` but nothing for its rows/columns db-pointer member `mat`. What you're doing `malloc()`ing anything in C++ is beyond me anyway, but this specifically is walking you straight into **undefined behavior**.

Comment: It's probably the program, not the compiler, that gives you a segfault? Tried a debugger?

Comment: You are also filling row 3 of matrix that has only rows 0, 1, 2.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
matrix* tMat = (matrix*)malloc(sizeof(matrix));
```

I'm not entirely sure what you are expecting this to do, but it probably doesn't do that... In fact, it doesn't do much at all, other than create a block of memory large enough for a the struct `matrix`. It is filled with some random garbage (which may or may not be zeros).

You then go on and use it:

```
                tMat->mat[j][i] += matA->mat[j][m] * matB->mat[m][i];
```

which most likely means you are either accessing NULL or some random garbage address that isn't valid. You then return the pointer to it, which is not freed here:

```
matrix* matC = MultiplyMat(&matA,&matB);
PrintMatrix(matC);

return 0;
```

You probably want something like:

```
matrix* tMat = new matrix(matB->col, matA->row);
```

But you would be much better off creating a `matrix operator*(const matrix& a, const matrix& b)`, so you don't return a pointer at all. The overhead will be pretty small.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I changed the line just for debugging, I edited my answer, you can see the complete code above, it is also giving error with the above edited question code

Comment: +1 Beyond even that, the `matrix` class doesn't clean up its own allocated memory which should be done in conjunction with implementing proper [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) semantics one way or another (smart pointers ideally), and *both* of those should be done prior to implementing value-returning functionality. In short, this code is only about half-way where it needs to be to do this right.

Comment: You're not a fortran programmer by any chance? You are filling your matrix the wrong way around [or sizing the wrong way], as `matA[3][0]=5;` goes wrong according to gdb - I didn't really check for such things when I wrote my reply...

Comment: thanx for your response! :)
I have found the mistake(it is more of typing mistake than segmentation fault), 
in the print function
for( int i=0;tMat->row;i++ )
it should be i<tMat->row

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix actually has a constructor but it isn't called when allocation memory using `malloc()`. You clearly want to use

```
matrix* tMat = new matrix(m, n);
```

with suitable argument `m` and `n`. Well, actually, you rather want to use

```
std::unique_ptr<matrix> tMat(new matrix(m, n));
```

... but this is just related to the next problem you'll get once you get past your segmentation fault: you also need to clean up resources. It is also not quite what your really want, though, because you really want something like this:

```
matrix MultiplyMat(matrix const& a, matrix const& b) {
     // ...
     matrix result(m, n);
     // ...
     return result;
}
```

Comment: @SaadAbdullah: sure. You'll need to include `<memory>` to use `std::unique_ptr<T>`. ... and you'll need to have a C++11 compiler (if you are compiling with C++03 you can use `std::auto_ptr<T>` instead; this class template is also declared in `<memory>`).

Comment: found it! :)
though I found the error! but
+1 for the unique_ptr